# Amazon question: Can different pen names under the same KDP account be publicly connected?

Tags: pseudonym

If I put two pen names under the same KDP account, is there any way for the public to find out that they are written by the same person? KDP says 'no', but sometimes the official version isn't the truth.

Thanks.

Comment: What does KDP stand for?

Answer (score 1):

I guess nothing's completely secure once it's online, but I think barring hackers or a catastrophic data leak you should be fine.

I've got more than one pen name on the same KDP account, and I can't see any links between them. You can check out "Kate Sherwood" and "Catherine Dale" if you want to poke around yourself and look for connections.

Comment: Does the name on the copyright need to be my real name? If so, how do I avoid readers connecting my pseudonym and real name! Thanks.

Comment: The name on the copyright doesn't have to be your real name; you can use a penname. You do need an address for the copyright registration, at least in the US so if someone is REALLY hunting you down, they might figure it out. You could use a PO Box in some city you visit a few times a year (there's no real reason for the copyright office to send you anything, so you wouldn't have to check regularly) or use the address of a trusted friend or family member. But the name itself doesn't have to be your real name.